# How to "disable" a file output stream

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I'm working on some legacy code in which there are **a lot** of WriteLn(F, '...') commands scattered pretty much all over the place. There is some useful information in these commands (what information variables contain, etc), so I'd prefer not to delete it or comment it out, but I want to stop the program from writing the file.

Is there any way that I can assign the F variable so that anything written to it is ignored? We use the console output, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going back a long long time to the good old days of DOS - If you assign 'f' to the device 'nul', then there should be no output.

```
assign (f, 'nul')
```

I don't know whether this still works in Windows.

Edit:
You could also assign 'f' to a file - assignfile (f, 'c:\1.txt') - for example.

Comment: Your edit: the question says "stop the program writing the file". As a note it is now AssignFile(F,[...]) rather than Assign

Answer (score 0):

Opening the null device and letting output go there would probably work.  Under DOS, the performance of the NUL device was astonishingly bad IIRC (from what I understand, it wasn't buffered, so the system had to look up NUL in the device table when processing each byte) but I would not be at all surprised if it's improved under newer systems.  In any case, that's probably the easiest thing you can do unless you really need to maximize performance.  If performance is critical, it might in theory be possible to override the WriteLn function so it does nothing for certain files, but unfortunately I believe it allows syntax forms that were not permissible for any user-defined functions.

Otherwise, I would suggest doing a regular-expression find/replace to comment out the WriteLn statements in a fashion that can be mechanically restored.

Comment: `cat HugeISOFile.iso > NUL` returns pretty fast; I'm sure there's no performance issue with the use of `NUL`!

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: Under Unix variants, probably.  Not sure about under Windows.  In any case, I didn't want anyone to rely upon the solution without testing to ensure that it would work acceptably, since under DOS sending output to NUL was actually slower than sending it to a hard drive file!

Comment: I've ran the `cat` on Windows, not Unix.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: Okay.  I would have expected a Windows user to use "TYPE", but in any case it's good to know that the system is now faster at doing nothing.

Comment: Yup, I'd expect a Windows user to use `type` as well, but I typed `cat` and it worked; Linux habits! When I saw your comment I double-checked on both Windows 7 and Windows XP, the `cat` command is there on both.

Comment: @Cosmin, cat is not a standard Windows command. It's not on my Windows 7 system. You probably installed some Unix command-line tools.